# How to query a polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `jobs` table and an `activities` table. One Job can have many Activities. The relation is polymorphic.

Tables:

```
job         activities
----------- -------------
id          id
...         target_id
            target_type
            ...
```

Models pseudo-code:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :activities, :as => :target, :dependent => :delete_all
  # ...
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
  # ...
end
```

The state of a given Job is determined by the state of the last Activity it relates to, like below (the last in this case is the last created, so we can safely order by id).

```
Job +-> Activity 1 - state: new        |
    +-> Activity 2 - state: submitted  +--> Job state is approved
    `-> Activity 3 - state: approved   |
```

How would you query only the Jobs that are on a given state, using ActiveRecord and Rails 3/4?

It also (just) occurred to me the idea to, instead of doing this query altogether, use something like "counter caches" uses and denormalize the relationship. I would store the state on the jobs table and keeping it sync'ed using an `after_create` hook on the `Activity` model? Something along this lines:

```
after_create :update_state

def update_state
  target.update_attribute(state: self.state) if target.respond_to?(:state)
end
```

Would this be a viable alternative to solve the problem in a simpler way?

Comment: I think you already have the simplest solutions. I would go with the second method because checking jobs with certain states will take a long time.

Comment: you can try using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine the polymorphism would be an issue here (it's just a way to select the right data)

---

**State Machine**

What about using a [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

From the looks of it, you're over-engineering your models. Your `Job` has the state, not the `activity`, so why complicate by using another model?

If you use a state machine, the state of an object is handled natively, like this:

```
#app/models/job.rb
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

state_machine :initial => :new do

        #States
        state :new
        state :submitted
        state :approved

        ### Events ###

        #Submit
        event :submit do
        transition :new => :submitted
        end

        #Approve
        event :approve do
        transition :submitted => :approved
        end
    end

end
```

This will handle the `Job` state using a `state` attribute in your jobs model directly

The most important aspect of this is the use of the [`state-machine` events](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#example):

```
#State Machine Functions
@job = Job.find(id)

@job.state        #-> "new"
@job.new?         #-> false
@job.submitted?   #-> false
@job.approved?    #-> true

@job.submit!      #-> state: "new" -> "submitted"
@job.approve!     #-> state: "submitted" -> "approved"
```

---

**Scopes**

If you didn't want to remove your `activity` model, you may wish to use `scopes` instead

Although I know you can use this, I'm not sure if the syntax is correct with a polymorphic association:

```
#app/models/job.rb
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :submitted, -> { joins(:activity).where(state: "submitted") }
    scope :activity, ->(activity = new) { joins(:activity).where(state: activity) }
end
```